# Get data using flask in batches

Tags: python, flask, text, server

I want to get data from url, this data is a json format that contains 500,000 **ids** as keys and **text** as values, but the server limits the data to length 1000 per time, which means that I can not get more than 1000 values every time I run the app.

Then, I wrote a for loop that to get 1000 by 1000 values but this is what I get

```
j =  1000
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2022 16:51:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
j =  1000
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2022 16:52:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
j =  1000
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2022 16:52:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

which means that the first loop only was executed, and then the app stops.
What I want is to get the 500,000 by looping or refreshing the app with new values of i and j.
Is there a better way to do this?

The Code:

```
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_pydantic import validate
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    dialects = pd.read_csv('Data/dialect_dataset.csv')
    df = dialects.copy()
    df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
    IDs = list(df['id'].values)
    # print(IDs)
    
    
    @app.route('/', methods = ["GET" , "POST"])
    @validate()
    def get_json():
        url = "https://XXXX.XXXX/XXXX"
        j = 0
        for i in range(len(IDs)):
    
            if i % 1000 == 0 and j <= len(IDs):
                i = j
                j += 1000
                print("j = ",j)

            elif j >= len(IDs):
                j = len(IDs)
            
            try:
                uResponse = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(IDs[i:j]), 
                                            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
                data = uResponse.text
    
                with open('Data/text_data.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(data)
                return data
    
            except:
                return "Something Happened"
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I don't see any `while` in your code.

Comment: `return` exits function at once - so your `return data` exits `for`-loop with first `response` and it never run next `requests`. If you want to run requests many times then you should put `data` on list and use `return list_with_all_data` after `for`-loop. OR simply remove `return data`

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear.
Thank you but the problem is not returning all the data, I want to get 1000 value each time.

Comment: when you run any function then it always starts from the beginning. You would have to remeber values in global variable to keep previous content - it means `j` and `i`. And you don't need `for`-loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you run any function then it always starts from the beginning - and it use the same values.

You have to remeber values `i`, `j` in global variables to keep changed values.

And `for`-loop is useless for this.

Something like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
from flask import Flask
from flask_pydantic import validate

app = Flask(__name__)

dialects = pd.read_csv('Data/dialect_dataset.csv')
df = dialects.copy()
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
IDs = list(df['id'].values)
# print(IDs)

# it creates global variables
j = 0
loop_i = -1

url = "https://XXXX.XXXX/XXXX"

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET" , "POST"])
@validate()
def get_json():
    global loop_i   # inform function to keep values in global variables
    global j

    # instead of `for`-loop. 
    # I use `loop_i` instead of `i` because you change `i` in next lines.
    loop_i += 1
    if loop_i >= len(IDs):
        return
    i = loop_i


    if i % 1000 == 0 and j <= len(IDs):
        i = j
        j += 1000
        print("j = ",j)

    elif j >= len(IDs):
        j = len(IDs)
    
    try:
        uResponse = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(IDs[i:j]), 
                                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        data = uResponse.text

        with open('Data/text_data.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            outfile.write(data)
        return data

    except:
        return "Something Happened"
```

---

Or you could try to use `yield data` instead of `return data` and in next execution it should start function after `yield` instead of starting at the beginning. So it would loop like withiout exiting function.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
from flask import Flask
from flask_pydantic import validate

app = Flask(__name__)

dialects = pd.read_csv('Data/dialect_dataset.csv')
df = dialects.copy()
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(str)
IDs = list(df['id'].values)
# print(IDs)


@app.route('/', methods = ["GET" , "POST"])
@validate()
def get_json():
    url = "https://XXXX.XXXX/XXXX"
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(IDs)):

        if i % 1000 == 0 and j <= len(IDs):
            i = j
            j += 1000
            print("j = ",j)

        elif j >= len(IDs):
            j = len(IDs)
        
        try:
            uResponse = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(IDs[i:j]), 
                                        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
            data = uResponse.text

            with open('Data/text_data.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                outfile.write(data)
            yield data   # <-- yield instead of return

        except:
            return "Something Happened"
```